# How to override the default struct constructor

Tags: d

I have a struct that needs to keep track of the number of created instances and uses it as a unique ID. Hence in the default constructor I need to update a static variable such as this:

```
struct Wire {
    int x, y, id;
    static int instanceCount;

    this() {
        this.id = instanceCount++;
    }
}
```

I do not wish to disable the default constructor. Currently I am using a class to work-around it.

Answer (score 1):

Those are your options in D. Use a class and be able to define no-argument constructors, or use a struct and not be able to do this. The reasons for it apparently have to deal with D's .init functionality. Another workaround would be to use a separate factory function that constructs Wire, updates instanceCount, and returns Wire.

What you're doing sounds like makes much more sense with classes, anyway. It's more expected for classes to have 'instances' and class state like `instanceCount`. If you only want structs so that you can allocate them on the stack, you can actually do this with classes: `scope s = new S()`

Answer (score 0):

As @verne already point outyou should use classes for that. Another way is use static opCall, but it is not perfect solution:

```
import std.stdio;

struct Wire {
    int x, y, id;
    static int instanceCount;

    static opCall() {
        Wire w;
        w.id = instanceCount++;
        return w;   
    }
}

void main()
{
    auto s0 = Wire();
    auto s1 = Wire();
    writeln(s0);
    writeln(s1);
}
```